# How to clear text fields when a monotouch app is being closed/sent to background?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is there a way to clear text fields when a Xamarin/iOS app is entering background so that when the app comes to foreground it is ready for user input ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389323/how-to-get-notified-with-monotouch-about-my-application-being-closed-sent-to-bac

Answer (score 3):

In the view controller you're concerned about, add this to LoadView or similar:

```cs
 UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveWillResignActive( ResignActive );
```

and then clear your fields in ResignActive:

```cs
void ResignActive (object sender, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotificationEventArgs args)
{
    this.TextField.Text = "";
}
```

The resign active notification happens when the app is about to be interrupted. Putting this in your view controller avoids cluttering the app delegate with callbacks, and keeps the logic near the ui.

Answer (score 0):

in your AppDelegate

```cs
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
{
    // App entered background, do some light stuff here, 
    // there is not much time before getting suspended
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried first before posting, but Text Fields properties are not "visible" in the app delegate.

Comment: Do you have a NavigationController?  If so, you should be able to access the "current" View Controller from your AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can add an observer, the observer will notice when the controller comes to the foreground.

In your controller constructor add:

> NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.WillEnterForegroundNotification,
>   EnteredForeground);

And then add the function

```cs
    void EnteredForeground(NSNotification notification)
    {
        if (IsViewLoaded && View.Window != null)
        { 
            if (AppDelegate.willEnterForeground)
            {
                // Clear your textfields
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you try to modify the UI on the enteredForeground notification, you will see the UI change when it comes to the foreground. UI updates need to happen before then.